# How do I create a 2d array in C++ that contains the counter of the loop in one part and a list of numbers in the other part?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, random

I am trying to count the number of occurrences of a randomly generated number in 3 different cases: 10, 1,000, and 100,000 iterations. In each iteration, I would like to count the number of occurrences of numbers 1 to 6 and then later on compare these counts.

This is my idea of implementation: Have a nested `for` loop where the outer one will iterate from case 1 to case 3 and the inner `for` loop will generate a random number for each case, count the frequency of occurrence and put that into an array.

When I exit the inner `fo`r loop, I would like to take that array and put it inside another array which is 2d so it saves the values for each case.

Here's my C++ code for that so far:

```
extern "C"{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
}
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int genRand(){
    int min = 1;
    int max = 6;
    int randNum = min + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (max - min + 1) + 1);
    return randNum;
}

int main(){

//Seeds the random number generator(takes the current time and uses it to randomize)
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

//Part 1 - Roll a single die 10, 1000, and 100 000 times

//First part holds the number of cases and the second hold the number of occurances
int randArr[3][6] = {0};
int countArr[6] = {0};

int mult = 1; int randNum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<10*mult; j++){
        randNum = genRand();
        for(int k = 1; k<=6; k++){
            if(randNum == k) { countArr[k-1]++;}
        }
    }
    mult *= 100;
    randArr[i][i] = i, countArr[i];
    }
}
```

I believe my last line is wrong but I don't understand why or how to make a 2d array such that the first part is the case number(which in this case would be i) and then the second input would be the array I created earlier with the frequency of occurrences.

Could someone help point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Sailanarmo The stdlib.h and time.h files are created for C not C++ so if I want to use the from C++, I need to let the compiler know that the files are in C syntax.

Comment: Can anyone else confirm this? I am genuinely curious about that. Because C++ is an extension of C, and I would assume the compiler is smart enough to determine what is C and and what is C++.

Comment: have you tried changing your line from [i][i] to [i][j]?

Comment: @Sailanarmo you should learn to use google for questions like that. It can save everyone time and you have the opportunity to learn something new.

Comment: Instead of using `countArr`, why not increment `randArr[i][randNum - 1]` directly. No need to copy. No need for the `k`-loop.

Comment: Look at using a struct to contain each row in which one member of the struct is the case number and the second member of the struct is the array of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify your code greatly to reduce the complexity of this problem.

The simplest idiom for accomplishing this is to use a map. `std::map` uses a tree structure to save the data, `std::unordered_map` uses a hash table. The latter is (usually) faster, but the former requires less typing. Both will work fine for this problem.

The other major change is that you should generally not use `rand()` or its related utilities for generating random numbers. Use the `<random>` library in C++11 and later. If you actually do intend to use `rand()` because you're expressly testing its statistical randomness, then that's fine, but I'm including the altered code to "correctly" generate random numbers if that's what you need/expect. Replace it with your old code if necessary.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <map>
#include<array>

int genRand(){
    //Generate Random numbers with an engine
    static std::mt19337 engine(std::random_device{}());
    //Easy-to-configure distribution algorithm
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1, 6);
    //Pass the engine into the distribution and it will correctly give you the result you want
    return distribution(engine);
}

int main(){
    int mult = 10;
    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        //Construct the map
        std::map<int, int> map;
        for(int j = 0; j < mult; j++) {
            //Generate the number
            int randNum = genRand();
            //The brackets operator does a lot of work: if the entry already exists, it 
            //simply returns a reference to it. If it does not, it creates a new entry,
            //value-initializes it (sets it to 0), and then returns a reference.
            //We then increment this reference.
            ++map[randNum];
        }
        std::cout << "Results for " << mult << " iterations:" << std::endl;
        for(auto const& result : map) {
            //We can iterate over the results. std::map will keep the results sorted
            //automatically, because it uses the natural ordering of the key
            std::cout << "    " << "Number: " << result.first << "; Occurrences: " << result.second << std::endl;
        }
        mult *= 100;
    }
}
```

Possible Output from this program:

```
Results for 10 iterations:
    Number: 1; Occurrences: 2
    Number: 2; Occurrences: 2
    Number: 3; Occurrences: 1
    Number: 4; Occurrences: 1
    Number: 5; Occurrences: 1
    Number: 6; Occurrences: 3
Results for 1000 iterations:
    Number: 1; Occurrences: 154
    Number: 2; Occurrences: 184
    Number: 3; Occurrences: 179
    Number: 4; Occurrences: 162
    Number: 5; Occurrences: 172
    Number: 6; Occurrences: 149
Results for 100000 iterations:
    Number: 1; Occurrences: 16811
    Number: 2; Occurrences: 16666
    Number: 3; Occurrences: 16534
    Number: 4; Occurrences: 16815
    Number: 5; Occurrences: 16577
    Number: 6; Occurrences: 16597
```

Comment: `std::map` gives the code the flexibility to scale to any range or set of numbers to test, but in this specific case it's just slower then using a `std::array` that would be sufficient.

Comment: Note that using `std::random_device` will take away entropy from the system's random device, leaving less for cryptographic algorithms.  And there's not necessarily any need to get a cryptographically secure random seed for this type of application.  On Linux, for example, I tend to just seed the mt19937 algorithm with the time and getpid() for this type of test.

Comment: @DanielSchepler `std::random_device` is not cryptographically secure, and no implementation even attempts to guarantee that it is. It's just a potential source of entropy, and using it like this is exactly how most users of this library recommend it be used. It's true that it uses up some of the entropy maintained by its underlying implementation, but using it once at the initialization of an application leaves plenty of time for the entropy to recover and be usable by other applications. I think you need to spend some time revisiting what these algorithms/objects are.